# AlertDialog not dismissing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I'm making a small game and I'm trying to show an AlertDialog, the problem is, when the user clicks on an option the AlertDialog won't dissapear.

I'm using loopers so my game thread stops (looper) when my AlertDialog appears and when the user clicks "Cancel" the game thread runs again but the dialog is on top and the user can't keep playling.

```
public void alerta(){
    Looper.prepare(); 
    myHandler = new Handler();


    AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    alertadd.setView(view);
    alertadd.setNeutralButton("Tomar Foto", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                stops++;
                Toast.makeText(_context.getApplicationContext(), "Tomaste Foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    alertadd.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            System.out.println("Stops = "+stops);
            stops++;
            Toast.makeText(_context.getApplicationContext(), "Cancelar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myHandler.getLooper().quit();
            dlg.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertadd.show();
    Looper.loop();      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether It's gonna help, but try

```
dlg.cancel();
```

or have a look at this. it works perfectly fine in my case:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.a))
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.b), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
})
    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.c), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: I'm sure that works, but I think my problem is related to my looper

Answer (score 0):

It should be `alertadd.dismiss();`. And NOT `dlg.dismiss();`

Try that. If not let me know...

Comment: No luck, "The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create alert dialog first, then use it's dismiss() method in onClick method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.a))
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.b), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
})
 .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.c), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    alert.dismiss();
 }
});
alert.show()
```